Geometric Levy motion
Which Levy processes $(L_t)$ admit a  geometric motion, i.e., an almost sure global solution of
$$
dX_t = X_tdL_t\\
X_0=1
$$
(for some sensible but unspecified notion of "solution")?
If the solution is some sort of limit of Euler discretizations, then
$$
\log(X_1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_i \log(1+ dL_{i/n, (i+1)/n}) \\ \sim \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(1+dL^{(i)}_{1/n})
$$
which makes me think the Levy measure must be supported in $(-1, \infty)$ (the probability that none of the $n$ terms is negative infinity converges to $e^{-\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \nu(x)dx}$ I believe).
If this is indeed a necessary condition, the next question is whether it's sufficient. Since $\log(1+x)<x$, the Euler discretizations of $X_1$ are bounded by $e^{L_1}$. Since they're also non-negative, I'd be surprised if they didn't converge in some sense, but 10 years after doing this in my studies, I'm lacking the skills to prove it.

The solution to your equation is called a Doléan-Dade exponential.

@shiva Thanks. I have some follow up questions (feel free to recommend I open new questions for these): Theorem 23.8 of Kallenberg proves existence and the explicit formula $\exp(X_t - [X_t]^c)\prod_{s\leq t} (1+\Delta X_s)\exp(-\Delta X_s)$ of the Dolean-Dade exponential. He states "Note that the infinite product in (6) is a.s. absolutely convergent, since $\sum_{s\leq t} (∆X_s)^2 ≤ [X]_t < \infty$. However, we may have ∆Xs = −1 for some s > 0,
in which case Z = 0 for t ≥ s.". My questions are

(1) (EDIT: figured it out myself) (2) What happens if $\Delta X_s<-1$? Does this happen infrequently enough that the definition works out and just flips signs in a regular fashion?

Re (2): it seems to me you can just separate from the infinite product the finitely many jumps (over any fixed interval) smaller than -1, which can cause the Dolean-Dade exponential to flip signs, and then the convergence of the infinite product is analysis 101. I'm just surprised that the solution of a notion of exponential equation takes on negative signs, and confused Kallenberg deems the fact that the solution can be zero more noteworthy than that it can be negative.
